# How to redirect from subdomain to url in domain using AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, subdomain, amazon-route53

Need redirect from blog.example.com to [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog) using AWS Route53, preserving queries.

Also need to set up smart redirects i.e. blog.example.com/articles/slug to [www.example.com/blog/slug](http://www.example.com/blog/slug)

Need to avoid double redirects too.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with Route53.

[I would recommend instead using an Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html). You can create rules that match based on host and path, and route to specific target groups.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this with pointing subdomain to Load Balancer in Route53 (A record) and Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name blog.example.com;
    rewrite ^/articles/(.*) https://www.example.com/blog/$1 permanent;

    return 301 https://www.example.com/blog/blog$request_uri;
}
```